# Total number of subgroups of a non cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I m working on total number of subgroups of any group. I m quite clear about cyclic groups but i m facing difficulties in non cyclic groups. Euler formula is useful for cyclic groups i m worried about non cyclic. My question is.. How can i calculate total number of subgroups of a  non cyclic group?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. It seems you forgot to state a question.

Comment: Oopss i forgot. Thanks

Comment: It is really quite difficult to classify the subgroups of a group in general; the cyclic case is much easier than the general case. Already the case of an arbitrary finite abelian group is tricky. If someone asks you this question you'll be taking heavy advantage of specific facts about the group involved.